# React Native - Alert.alert doesn't seem to call function

Tags: javascript, react-native

My sign out user function does not seem to work at all. I am calling it from an alert in login, but it doesn't seem to call it. If I try to add "()" at the end it just gives me an error.

```
loginUser = (email, password) => {
      try {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user){
          console.log(user)
          console.log('we are logged in boys')
          Alert.alert(
            'Signed In',
            'You have signed in. Well done!',
            [
              {text: 'Sign Out', onPress: () => this.signOutUser},
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          )
        })
      }
      catch(error) {
        console.log(error.toString())
      }
    }

    signOutUser = () => {
      console.log('Do we reach this or not')
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function (user){
        // Sign-out successful.
        console.log('We are signing out!')
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
        console.log('There is an issue!')
      });
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting when you call `this. signOutUser()`? You current code is not calling `signOutUser` function.

Comment: I get the error
this.signOutUser is not a function. (In 'this.signOutUser()', 'this.signOutUser' is undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside `signInWithEmailAndPassword` callback is not what you are expecting. change the callback function to [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), like

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
  ...
});
```

Also, change the assignment onPress function as

```
{text: 'Sign Out', onPress: this.signOutUser}
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Update your function with arrow function:

```
loginUser = (email, password) => {
      try {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user)=> {
          console.log(user)
          console.log('we are logged in boys')
          Alert.alert(
            'Signed In',
            'You have signed in. Well done!',
            [
              {text: 'Sign Out', onPress: () => this.signOutUser()},//Or Write  this.signOutUser direct without arrow function
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          )
        })
      }
      catch(error) {
        console.log(error.toString())
      }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
{text: 'Sign Out', onPress: () => { this.signOutUser(); } }
```

Comment: If I change it to that, I get
this2.signOutUser() is not a function. (In '_this2.signOutUser()','_this2.signOutUser' is undefined)

Comment: @ManJames You first have to edit your main function and have to define it as arrow function like this.`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
 ///code here 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Update your function like this

```
loginUser = (email, password) => {
      try {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user)=> {
          console.log(user)
          console.log('we are logged in boys')
          Alert.alert(
            'Signed In',
            'You have signed in. Well done!',
            [
              {text: 'Sign Out', onPress: () => this.signOutUser},
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          )
        })
      }
      catch(error) {
        console.log(error.toString())
      }
    }
```

The function inside then() should be pointer function so that it can access `this` context